# are images loaded once in html then available for subsequent requests?

Tags: html, image

If I've loaded an image into an html page, when I load it a second time further down in that page will it be instantly available?

Comment: I know this is a really simple one.

Comment: Depends on the headers sent with the image, but I believe most browsers will cache images automatically. That should work fine as long as the URL is the same. Check the network request to make sure the image is only being requested once from the server.

Comment: I'd accept that as an answer if you want to drop it down there.

Comment: Roger, Hope it helped!

Comment: thanks yeah, its nice to validate these things we believe. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the headers sent with the image, but I believe most browsers will cache images automatically. That should work fine as long as the URL is the same. Check the network request to make sure the image is only being requested once from the server.